# SpellNumber to words not using the appropriate currency denomination

Tags: excel, vba, numbers

The below code is a custom spellnumber where i search(vlookup) for a value in cell H19 (Sheet "BEST") from sheet "DataList" array B2:E23 and get the value of the third and fourth column to be displayed in the function spell number. I dont want to use Dollars only and i have given the option to select the currency type in H19. Based on the currency type selected (H19) it should display the total amount in cell i22 with that corresponding selected currency (AED - Dirham) and its smaller value/ denomination (Fils) in the place of its decimals in words.

Example H19 dropdown list selection is AED. The value of cell i22 is 2000.38, Cell C22 where the function spellnumber is used would display as "Two Thousand Dirham and Thirty Eight Fils only" based on the selected currency symbol in H19 and the word "Dirham" is the result of the third column and "fils" from the fourth column from the array B2:E23 in "DataList" sheet when H19 "AED" is matched with the array.

The code result is only displaying "Two Thousand Dirham and Thirty Eight Cents Only". The first portion is correct and ending is wrong which should be "fils". This is the value in array  B2:E23 in "DataList" sheet.

```
Option Explicit

'Main Function
Function SpellNumber(ByVal MyNumber)
Dim Dollars, Cents, Temp
Dim DecimalPlace, Count
ReDim Place(9) As String
Place(2) = " Thousand "
Place(3) = " Million "
Place(4) = " Billion "
Place(5) = " Trillion "

' String representation of amount.
MyNumber = Trim(Str(MyNumber))

' Position of decimal place 0 if none.
DecimalPlace = InStr(MyNumber, ".")

' Convert cents and set MyNumber to dollar amount.
If DecimalPlace > 0 Then
    Cents = GetTens(Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & "00", 2))
    MyNumber = Trim(Left(MyNumber, DecimalPlace - 1))
End If

Count = 1
Do While MyNumber <> ""
    Temp = GetHundreds(Right(MyNumber, 3))
    If Temp <> "" Then Dollars = Temp & Place(Count) & Dollars
    If Len(MyNumber) > 3 Then
        MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 3)
    Else
        MyNumber = ""
    End If
    Count = Count + 1
Loop

Select Case CheckSymbol()
    Case ""
        Dollars = "No Dollars"
    Case Else
        Dollars = Dollars & CheckSymbol()
End Select

Select Case Cents
    Case ""
        Cents = " and No Cents Only"
    Case "One"
        Cents = " and One Cent Only"
    Case Else
        Cents = " and " & Cents & " Cents Only"
End Select

SpellNumber = Dollars & Cents
End Function

' Check symbol and get corresponding value
Function CheckSymbol() As String
Dim symbol As String
symbol = Sheets("BEST").Range("H19").Value

Select Case symbol
    Case "US$", "AED", "GBP£", "EUR€", "SAR", "AUD$", "BRLR$", "CAD$", "CNY¥", "HKD$", "INR?", "JPY¥", "MXN$", "NZD$", "NOK-kr", "RUB?", "SGD$", "ZAR-R", "KRW-?", "SEK-kr", "CHF", "TRY?"
        CheckSymbol = Application.VLookup(symbol, Sheets("DataList").Range("B2:E23"), 3, False)
    Case Else
        CheckSymbol = " US Dollars"
End Select
End Function

' Converts a number from 100-999 into text
Function GetHundreds(ByVal MyNumber)
Dim Result As String
If Val(MyNumber) = 0 Then Exit Function
MyNumber = Right("000" & MyNumber, 3)

' Convert the hundreds place.
If Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1) <> "0" Then
    Result = GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1)) & " Hundred "
End If

' Convert the tens and ones place.
If Mid(MyNumber, 2, 1) <> "0" Then
    Result = Result & GetTens(Mid(MyNumber, 2))
Else
    Result = Result & GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 3))
End If

GetHundreds = Result
End Function


' Converts a number from 10 to 99 into text.
Function GetTens(TensText)
Dim Result As String
Result = "" ' Null out the temporary function value.
If Val(Left(TensText, 1)) = 1 Then ' If value between 10-19...
    Select Case Val(TensText)
        Case 10: Result = "Ten"
        Case 11: Result = "Eleven"
        Case 12: Result = "Twelve"
        Case 13: Result = "Thirteen"
        Case 14: Result = "Fourteen"
        Case 15: Result = "Fifteen"
        Case 16: Result = "Sixteen"
        Case 17: Result = "Seventeen"
        Case 18: Result = "Eighteen"
        Case 19: Result = "Nineteen"
        Case Else
    End Select
Else ' If value between 20-99...
    Select Case Val(Left(TensText, 1))
        Case 2: Result = "Twenty "
        Case 3: Result = "Thirty "
        Case 4: Result = "Forty "
        Case 5: Result = "Fifty "
        Case 6: Result = "Sixty "
        Case 7: Result = "Seventy "
        Case 8: Result = "Eighty "
        Case 9: Result = "Ninety "
        Case Else
    End Select
    Result = Result & GetDigit(Right(TensText, 1)) ' Retrieve ones place.
End If

GetTens = Result
End Function


' Converts a number from 1 to 9 into text.
Function GetDigit(Digit)
Select Case Val(Digit)
    Case 1: GetDigit = "One"
    Case 2: GetDigit = "Two"
    Case 3: GetDigit = "Three"
    Case 4: GetDigit = "Four"
    Case 5: GetDigit = "Five"
    Case 6: GetDigit = "Six"
    Case 7: GetDigit = "Seven"
    Case 8: GetDigit = "Eight"
    Case 9: GetDigit = "Nine"
    Case Else: GetDigit = ""
End Select
End Function
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The reason is easy to find if you use the debugger and step through your code (F8): At the top of your code (below the comment `' Convert cents and set MyNumber to dollar amount.`), you are cutting of the amount after the the decimal point, therefore later `CentsText` is always "00".

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment. I have fixed the cents portion and edited but now i cant get it to display the decimals as "Centavos" which is the actual value in the from sheet "DataList" array B2:E23

Comment: Im very much sure it is in the "Check Symbol" area or Cents area in Function Spellnumber

Comment: Then go ahead and debug that function to check what is going on. It's your code and your data after all.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Much appreciated on your efforts <3

Answer (score 0):

Ok the answer is i added another CheckSymbol2 to get values for the cents portion and then integrated it in the Spellnumber area.

```
Option Explicit

'Main Function
Function SpellNumber(ByVal MyNumber)
Dim Dollars, Cents, Temp
Dim DecimalPlace, Count
ReDim Place(9) As String
Place(2) = " Thousand "
Place(3) = " Million "
Place(4) = " Billion "
Place(5) = " Trillion "

' String representation of amount.
MyNumber = Trim(Str(MyNumber))

' Position of decimal place 0 if none.
DecimalPlace = InStr(MyNumber, ".")

' Convert cents and set MyNumber to dollar amount.
If DecimalPlace > 0 Then
Cents = GetTens(Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & "00", 2))
MyNumber = Trim(Left(MyNumber, DecimalPlace - 1))
End If

Count = 1
Do While MyNumber <> ""
Temp = GetHundreds(Right(MyNumber, 3))
If Temp <> "" Then Dollars = Temp & Place(Count) & Dollars
If Len(MyNumber) > 3 Then
    MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 3)
Else
    MyNumber = ""
End If
Count = Count + 1
Loop

Select Case CheckSymbol()
Case ""
    Dollars = "No Dollars"
Case Else
    Dollars = Dollars & CheckSymbol()
End Select

Select Case Cents
Case ""
    Cents = " and No " & CheckSymbol2 & " Only"
Case "One"
    Cents = " and One " & CheckSymbol2() & " Only"
Case Else
    Cents = " and " & Cents & " " & CheckSymbol2() & " Only"
End Select

' Existing code...

SpellNumber = Dollars & Cents
End Function

' Check symbol and get corresponding value
Function CheckSymbol() As String
Dim symbol As String

symbol = Sheets("BEST").Range("H19").Value


Select Case symbol
Case "US$", "AED", "GBP£", "EUR€", "SAR", "AUD$", "BRLR$", "CAD$", "CNY¥", "HKD$", "INR", "JPY¥", "MXN$", "NZD$", "NOK-kr", "RUB", "SGD$", "ZAR-R", "KRW", "SEK-kr", "CHF", "TRY"
    CheckSymbol = Application.VLookup(symbol,     Sheets("DataList").Range("B2:E23"), 3, False)
Case Else
    CheckSymbol = " US Dollars"
End Select


End Function


' Check symbol and get corresponding value for cents
Function CheckSymbol2() As String
Dim symbol2 As String
symbol2 = Sheets("BEST").Range("H19").Value

Select Case symbol2
Case "US$", "AED", "GBP£", "EUR€", "SAR", "AUD$", "BRLR$", "CAD$", "CNY¥", "HKD$", "INR", "JPY¥", "MXN$", "NZD$", "NOK-kr", "RUB", "SGD$", "ZAR-R", "KRW", "SEK-kr", "CHF", "TRY"
    CheckSymbol2 = Application.VLookup(symbol2, Sheets("DataList").Range("B2:E23"), 4, False)
Case Else
    CheckSymbol2 = "Cents"
End Select
End Function

' Converts a number from 100-999 into text
Function GetHundreds(ByVal MyNumber)
Dim Result As String
If Val(MyNumber) = 0 Then Exit Function
MyNumber = Right("000" & MyNumber, 3)

' Convert the hundreds place.
If Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1) <> "0" Then
Result = GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1)) & " Hundred "
End If

' Convert the tens and ones place.
If Mid(MyNumber, 2, 1) <> "0" Then
Result = Result & GetTens(Mid(MyNumber, 2))
Else
Result = Result & GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 3))
End If

GetHundreds = Result
End Function


' Converts a number from 10 to 99 into text.
Function GetTens(TensText)
Dim Result As String
Result = "" ' Null out the temporary function value.
If Val(Left(TensText, 1)) = 1 Then ' If value between 10-19...
Select Case Val(TensText)
    Case 10: Result = "Ten"
    Case 11: Result = "Eleven"
    Case 12: Result = "Twelve"
    Case 13: Result = "Thirteen"
    Case 14: Result = "Fourteen"
    Case 15: Result = "Fifteen"
    Case 16: Result = "Sixteen"
    Case 17: Result = "Seventeen"
    Case 18: Result = "Eighteen"
    Case 19: Result = "Nineteen"
    Case Else
End Select
Else ' If value between 20-99...
Select Case Val(Left(TensText, 1))
    Case 2: Result = "Twenty "
    Case 3: Result = "Thirty "
    Case 4: Result = "Forty "
    Case 5: Result = "Fifty "
    Case 6: Result = "Sixty "
    Case 7: Result = "Seventy "
    Case 8: Result = "Eighty "
    Case 9: Result = "Ninety "
    Case Else
End Select
Result = Result & GetDigit(Right(TensText, 1)) ' Retrieve ones place.
End If

GetTens = Result
End Function


' Converts a number from 1 to 9 into text.
Function GetDigit(Digit)
Select Case Val(Digit)
Case 1: GetDigit = "One"
Case 2: GetDigit = "Two"
Case 3: GetDigit = "Three"
Case 4: GetDigit = "Four"
Case 5: GetDigit = "Five"
Case 6: GetDigit = "Six"
Case 7: GetDigit = "Seven"
Case 8: GetDigit = "Eight"
Case 9: GetDigit = "Nine"
Case Else: GetDigit = ""
End Select
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to get it done :

```
Option Explicit
Function SpellNumber(ByVal MyNumber)
Dim Dollars, Cents, Temp
Dim DecimalPlace, Count
ReDim Place(9) As String
Place(2) = " Thousand "
Place(3) = " Million "
Place(4) = " Billion "
Place(5) = " Trillion "

' String representation of amount.
MyNumber = Trim(Str(MyNumber))

' Position of decimal place 0 if none.
DecimalPlace = InStr(MyNumber, ".")

' Convert cents and set MyNumber to dollar amount.
If DecimalPlace > 0 Then
    Cents = GetTens(Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & "00", 2))
    MyNumber = Trim(Left(MyNumber, DecimalPlace - 1))
End If

Count = 1
Do While MyNumber <> ""
    Temp = GetHundreds(Right(MyNumber, 3))
    If Temp <> "" Then Dollars = Temp & Place(Count) & Dollars
    If Len(MyNumber) > 3 Then
        MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 3)
    Else
        MyNumber = ""
    End If
    Count = Count + 1
Loop

Dim symbol As String
symbol = Sheets("BEST").Range("H19").Value

Select Case symbol
    Case "US$", "AED", "GBP£", "EUR€", "SAR", "AUD$", "BRLR$", "CAD$", "CNY¥", "HKD$", "INR", "JPY¥", "MXN$", "NZD$", "NOK-kr", "RUB?", "SGD$", "ZAR-R", "KRW", "SEK-kr", "CHF", "TRY"
        Dollars = Dollars & " " & Application.VLookup(symbol, Sheets("DataList").Range("B2:E23"), 3, False)
    Case Else
        Dollars = Dollars & " US Dollars"
End Select

Select Case Cents
    Case ""
        Cents = " and No Cents Only"
    Case "One"
        Dim symbol2 As String
        symbol2 = Sheets("BEST").Range("H19").Value
        Select Case symbol2
            Case "US$", "AED", "GBP£", "EUR€", "SAR", "AUD$", "BRLR$", "CAD$", "CNY¥", "HKD$", "INR", "JPY¥", "MXN$", "NZD$", "NOK-kr", "RUB", "SGD$", "ZAR-R", "KRW-W", "SEK-kr", "CHF", "TRY"
                Cents = " and One " & Application.VLookup(symbol2, Sheets("DataList").Range("B2:E23"), 4, False) & " Only"
            Case Else
                Cents = " and One Cent Only"
        End Select
    Case Else
      
        symbol2 = Sheets("BEST").Range("H19").Value
        Select Case symbol2
            Case "US$", "AED", "GBP£", "EUR€", "SAR", "AUD$", "BRLR$", "CAD$", "CNY¥", "HKD$", "INR", "JPY¥", "MXN$", "NZD$", "NOK-kr", "RUB", "SGD$", "ZAR-R", "KRW-W", "SEK-kr", "CHF", "TRY?"
                Cents = " and " & Cents & " " & Application.VLookup(symbol2, Sheets("DataList").Range("B2:E23"), 4, False) & " Only"
            Case Else
                Cents = " and " & Cents & " Cents Only"
        End Select
End Select

SpellNumber = Dollars & Cents
End Function


' Check symbol and get corresponding value
Function CheckSymbol() As String
Dim symbol As String

symbol = Sheets("BEST").Range("H19").Value


Select Case symbol
    Case "US$", "AED", "GBP£", "EUR€", "SAR", "AUD$", "BRLR$", "CAD$", "CNY¥", "HKD$", "INR?", "JPY¥", "MXN$", "NZD$", "NOK-kr", "RUB", "SGD$", "ZAR-R", "KRW-W", "SEK-kr", "CHF", "TRY"
        CheckSymbol = Application.VLookup(symbol, Sheets("DataList").Range("B2:E23"), 3, False)
    Case Else
        CheckSymbol = " US Dollars"
End Select


End Function


' Converts a number from 100-999 into text
Function GetHundreds(ByVal MyNumber)
Dim Result As String
If Val(MyNumber) = 0 Then Exit Function
MyNumber = Right("000" & MyNumber, 3)

' Convert the hundreds place.
If Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1) <> "0" Then
    Result = GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1)) & " Hundred "
End If

' Convert the tens and ones place.
If Mid(MyNumber, 2, 1) <> "0" Then
    Result = Result & GetTens(Mid(MyNumber, 2))
Else
    Result = Result & GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 3))
End If

GetHundreds = Result
End Function


' Converts a number from 10 to 99 into text.
Function GetTens(TensText)
Dim Result As String
Result = "" ' Null out the temporary function value.
If Val(Left(TensText, 1)) = 1 Then ' If value between 10-19...
    Select Case Val(TensText)
        Case 10: Result = "Ten"
        Case 11: Result = "Eleven"
        Case 12: Result = "Twelve"
        Case 13: Result = "Thirteen"
        Case 14: Result = "Fourteen"
        Case 15: Result = "Fifteen"
        Case 16: Result = "Sixteen"
        Case 17: Result = "Seventeen"
        Case 18: Result = "Eighteen"
        Case 19: Result = "Nineteen"
        Case Else
    End Select
Else ' If value between 20-99...
    Select Case Val(Left(TensText, 1))
        Case 2: Result = "Twenty "
        Case 3: Result = "Thirty "
        Case 4: Result = "Forty "
        Case 5: Result = "Fifty "
        Case 6: Result = "Sixty "
        Case 7: Result = "Seventy "
        Case 8: Result = "Eighty "
        Case 9: Result = "Ninety "
        Case Else
    End Select
    Result = Result & GetDigit(Right(TensText, 1)) ' Retrieve ones place.
End If

GetTens = Result
End Function


' Converts a number from 1 to 9 into text.
Function GetDigit(Digit)
Select Case Val(Digit)
    Case 1: GetDigit = "One"
    Case 2: GetDigit = "Two"
    Case 3: GetDigit = "Three"
    Case 4: GetDigit = "Four"
    Case 5: GetDigit = "Five"
    Case 6: GetDigit = "Six"
    Case 7: GetDigit = "Seven"
    Case 8: GetDigit = "Eight"
    Case 9: GetDigit = "Nine"
    Case Else: GetDigit = ""
End Select
End Function
```